# Conda glibc dependency conflict when installing new enviorment and python version

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have a fresh install of anaconda3 64bit python 3.8 and I am trying to setup an conda env with a different version of python 3.9.7

When I run `conda create -n py39 python=3.9.7 anaconda` the following error displays:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: / 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                          

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package python conflicts for:
python=3.9.7
anaconda -> anaconda-project==0.9.1=pyhd3eb1b0_1 -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|<4.0|>=2.7|>=3.6|>=3.5|>=3.7|>=3|>=3.6,<4.0|>=3.4|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>2.7|>=3,<3.7|3.7.*|3.8.*']
anaconda -> python[version='2.7.13|2.7.13|2.7.13|2.7.14|2.7.14|2.7.15|2.7.15|2.7.16|2.7.16|3.6.10|3.6.10|3.7.10|3.9.4|3.8.8|3.7.9|3.8.5|3.7.7|3.8.3|3.8.1|3.7.6|3.7.4|3.6.9|3.6.8|3.7.3|3.6.7|3.7.1|3.7.0|3.6.6|3.6.5|3.5.5|3.6.4|3.5.4|3.6.3|3.5.4|3.6.2|3.5.4|3.6.2|3.5.4|3.6.2|3.5.4|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0',build='h02fb82a_12|hfff3488_13|h0b30769_14|h417fded_24|hc3d631a_2|hc3d631a_0|h1571d57_0|h0371630_0|h9bab390_0|h265db76_1|h9bab390_7|hcff3b4d_5|h7579374_2|h7579374_1|h7579374_0|hdb3f193_0|hdb3f193_5|hcff3b4d_2|h0371630_0|h0371630_1|h0371630_2|h265db76_0|h0371630_0|h0371630_0|h0371630_7|h9bab390_6|hc3d631a_0|hc3d631a_4|hc3d631a_1|h1571d57_29|hc9025b9_1|he2c66cf_20|hc2b0042_21|hdfe5801_15|h72f0b78_15|heccc3f1_16|hc053d89_14|hac47a24_15|h2170f06_12']The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.23=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.23=0

Your installed version is: 2.23
```

I'm a bit confused on how to resolve this since the glibc version 2.23 and 2.23.0 should be the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about the GLIBC, but rather that Anaconda bundle doesn't have any builds that directly support Python v3.9.7. The newest version Anaconda is built with is v3.9.4. Instead, just specify minor version.

```bash
conda create -n py39 python=3.9 anaconda
```

Or if you want the newer Python, don't include `anaconda` and specify whatever packages you actually plan to use:

```bash
conda create -n py39 python=3.9
```

Comment: What's strange is when I run `conda search python`, it lists 3.9.7, your commands do indeed work

Comment: @pyCthon The `anaconda` *package* is a metapackage that includes dozens of packages. These packages are tested for interoperability and optimized, and therefore specify exact package versions and builds. Anaconda Cloud, however, still hosts newer releases of packages both on the `main` channel and via third-parties (e.g., `conda-forge`), which is why you find them in search. These are available for general environments.